# Finding if a Joda Time Duration is 0 seconds long

Tags: java, time, java-7, jodatime

First, I'm required to use Java 7, so I can't use SE8 Time stuff sadly though I'd love to learn it instead!

I have a List of Duration as follows:

```
List<Duration> durations;
```

Most of these values are about 8 hours long, but some are zero (intentionally). How do I check if they are 0 days, 0 minutes, 0 seconds and 0 ms long? Do I need to check each method as follows or is there a neater method?

```
for(Duration duration : durations){
    if(duration.getStandardDays() == 0 && 
       duration.getStandardHours() == 0 && 
       duration.getStandardSeconds() == 0){
        //do something
    }
}
```

The reason I ask is I notice there's the constant ZERO in the API, and I assume this is somehow linked into it. How do I compare to it instead? Or should I?

https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be able to do

```
if (duration.getMillis()==0)
```

[`getMillis()`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDuration.html#getMillis--) returns the length of the duration, in milliseconds.

Comment: Oh I had assumed that getMills() would just get the milliseconds, excluding seconds, minutes, hours, days etc. But that makes sense since it's not following the format of the getStandardDays(), getStandardHours(), etc. I'll accept your answer - thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `duration.isEqual(Duration.ZERO)`. The `isEqual` method is defined in [AbstractDuration.java](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDuration.html#isEqual-org.joda.time.ReadableDuration-) and the static `Duration.ZERO` value as defined [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#ZERO).

Answer (score 1):

## ThreeTen-Backport

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. It's team advises migration to the java.time classes.

Much of the java.time functionality of Java 8 and later is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

The [`org.threeten.backport.Duration`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Duration.html) class offers a [`isZero`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Duration.html#isZero()) method to test for zero length.

```
myDuration.isZero()
```